# Как получить индекс через $.each?

Tags: javascript

Как еще через `$.each` можно получить индекс без этого `let i = 0;` и `i++;` ?

```js
let obj = {
  423: 123,
  433: 2354,
  653: 345,
  783: 534534,
};

let i = 0;
$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
  console.log(i, k, v);
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не ясно в чём проблема. сейчас выводится всё, что вам нужно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, просто нужен был другой подход

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть отличный метод `Object.entries()`.

Работает он приблизительно так:

```js
let obj = {
  423: 123,
  433: 2354,
  653: 345,
  783: 534534,
};
console.log(obj);    
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

Для вашего случая:

```js
let obj = {
  423: 123,
  433: 2354,
  653: 345,
  783: 534534,
};

$.each(Object.entries(obj), function(i, [k, v]) { // здесь первый
                                                  // параметр i,
                                                  // а второй [k,v]
                                                  // (деструкторизация)
  console.log(i, k, v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Кстати говоря, есть и обратный метод Object.fromEntries().

```js
let obj = [
  ["423",123],
  ["433",2354],
  ["653",345],
  ["783",534534]
];
console.log(obj);    
console.log(Object.fromEntries(obj));
```

Comment: А чем отличается вывод данных от того, что у ТС?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а кто просил менять вывод?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вывод - ничем. способ получения индекса немного отличается. я расширю ответ.